# converting log4j into log4j2. With RollingFileAppender, size and file name pattern

Tags: log4j, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I must convert a file: log4j configuration from version 1 into 2.
But it must be really one to one.
The logs after this operation must look exactly as from log4j version 1.

Could you help me to convert it from log4j 1 into log4j2....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <appender name="mylog" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="mylog.log"/>
        <param name="RollingPolicy" value="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy"/>
        <param name="ActiveFileName" value="mylog.log"/>
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="mylog-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.rolled"/>
        <param name="TriggeringPolicy" value="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="100000"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%t] %p - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="mylogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="mylog"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="sysoutlog"/>
    </root>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: you should first try this first and post the issues you get.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're searching for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml> <!-- I use this just to get rid of eclipse XML schema warning -->
<Configuration status="warn" name="My configuration"> <!-- Modify status to get more verbose info -->
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="mylog" fileName="mylog.log"
        filePattern="mylog-%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.rolled">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%t] %p - %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100KB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="mylogger" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="mylog" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="sysoutlog" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Refer to [Docs of layout configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) for more formatting options.
Also if you intend to forward root logger to console, I'd add this appender

```
<Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT" />
```

and change root logger's appender to

```
<AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
```

Comment: instead of <!DOCTYPE xml> , a schema can be set on the root node, here `<Configuration status="debug" name="some" strict="true"
               xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config Log4j-config.xsd">
    <!-- schema found here:
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/logging-log4j2/master/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd
    -->`